# MySQL using a unique CHAR as primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, char, key

I'm fairly new to SQL programming, and I have a table that has two columns, UUID (a 32 CHAR unique hexstring), and permission
(just a permission for the system I'm using, like 'admin' or 'blacklist').

I'm not the greatest on the concept of the primary key, so I was wondering if its valid to use UUID as my primary key, considering it is 100% unique without whitespace, which I am already using to easily index my queries. I'm not joining the table with anything and more than likely never will, so is it valid to use the UUID as my primary key without any unforeseen consequences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is *valid* to use a UUID as a primary key.  It meets the two conditions required of a primary key:

- It is unique.
- It is never NULL.

However, it is a bad idea.  Why?  MySQL automatically clusters the data by the primary key.  That is, the data is actually sorted by the primary key.  UUIDs are not sequential.  Inserts can occur anywhere, requiring movement of data.

I would recommend a simple auto incremented primary key and declare the UUID as unique:

Comment: Or you could just leave out the primary key entirely, and declare UUID as unique.

Comment: @Barmar that would have the same effect in InnoDB.  If a primary key is not defined, and one non-nullable unique key is, that unique key becomes the clustered index.